# Arduino Yun - Uploading Sensor Data to Mysql on External Server

Tags: mysql, arduino-yun

Can Arduino Yun connect to MYSQL on External Server and store sensor data on it. If yes how?.

Comment: Unfamiliar with arduino but I understand the arduino-yun has ethernet and wifi to connect to a LAN and python to program it? Python can connect to a MySQL database on another computer so yes that should be possible then.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can.

1. You could write or port a mysql driver to the Arduino, but the small amount of memory and process power will make that no very easy.
2. With the Yún you could also install some libraries and program an app running on the linux side that forwards incoming data from the serial to your mysql database.

An other option:

3. Use an intermediary app to save incoming data to your database. The interface could be a typical HTTP API or via a publish/subscribe broker.

For simplicity I would recommend to go for option three.